# Section numbering disappeared after updating titlesec package

Tags: sectioning, numbering, titlesec, classicthesis

I'm using classicthesis to write my reports. I've always use the tweaked version of it since 2011 for my stuffs (e.g. back then it was for the master thesis). Today after updating the package in MiKTeX, something went wrong with the section numbering: the section and lower levels numbering are all disappeared (!) 
Before, it printed out all right:

> `1. My first section
>   1.1 First subsection
>   1.2 Second Subsection`

Now only the Section **title** is displayed, the numbering is gone:

> `My first section
>   First subsection
>   Second Subsection`

After some searching around I could narrow down the possible cause to be the latest version of `titlesec` package, but I don't know how to change either in the preamble of my main document with some options of `titlesec`, or go to the source of `classicthesis.sty` to modify some part.

For a long writing such as thesis, the structure is with `chapter` and `part` as the highest level, but for shorter writings, such as some 20-page report, I added one line to started with `section` as the highest level while avoiding numbering such as 0.1, 0.2

> `%this is to use section without chapter 0 numbering:
>   \renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`

Anyway, in always printed out section together with its number pretty fine, until the update of `titlesec` today. I know that classicthesis uses titlesec to play with the displaying of header lines, however in the code of `classicthesis.sty`, section is not numbered, so I'm rather at a loss now how to get back the numbering.

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: This goes with a quite complex external style file... Anyway someone report exactly the same problem in that is linked to this one. You can see a MWE there :) Don't know why I've searched on google and particularly on tex.stackexchange yet I missed that question.

Comment: fixed: [new version titlesec](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec)